# What is the theme that Nitrous.IO uses for Ruby syntax highlight?

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, nitrousio

https://i.stack.imgur.com/21pdx.png (or see below)
[image]

I want to use it in Sublime Text 3. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This theme seems to be CodeMirror's blackboard or midnight, see [here](http://codemirror.net/demo/theme.html).

[Blackboard](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#/Blackboard%20Black) is available on Sublime Text.

You may also look for other night bright themes to see if they fits:

https://sublime.wbond.net/browse/labels/color%20scheme

http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/

http://colorsublime.com/

https://github.com/theymaybecoders/sublime-tomorrow-theme

https://github.com/chriskempson/base16

https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/

https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes.git